# error[Error (E_UNKNOWN) Encountered an unexpected error] Details: MongoError: topology was destroyed

Tags: node.js, mongodb, zip, sails.js, waterline

This is my sample code for creating ZIP file.

```
exampleFunction: function(req, res, next){
     Test.create({....

     }).exec(function (error, HObj){
        if(error) {console.log('error'+ error); return next(error)};
        if(!HObj) {console.log('error'); return res.send({error : "error"});}
            var generatedUUID=uuid.v4().replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g,'_');
            var output = fs.createWriteStream(path.join(__dirname,'../../assets/images/'+generatedUUID+'.zip'));
            zipArchive.pipe(output);

            zipArchive.bulk([{ expand: true, cwd: path.join(__dirname,'../../assets/images/'), src: ['abc.mp3','xyz.mp3'], dest: 'newdir'}]);
            zipArchive.finalize();
            return res.send({zipName : generatedUUID+'.zip'});
    });
}
```

Calling this method in sailsjs controller continuously, that cause mongo error[`error[Error (E_UNKNOWN) Encountered an unexpected error] Details: MongoError: topology was destroyed`].

```
error: Sending 500 ("Server Error") response: 
 Error (E_UNKNOWN) :: Encountered an unexpected error
MongoError: topology was destroyed
    at Server.insert (/var/www/html/projects/RISHI/final/rishi-music_server/node_modules/sails-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:920:49)
    at Server.insert (/var/www/html/projects/RISHI/final/rishi-music_server/node_modules/sails-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/server.js:324:17)
    at executeCommands (/var/www/html/projects/RISHI/final/rishi-music_server/node_modules/sails-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/bulk/ordered.js:450:23)
    at OrderedBulkOperation.execute (/var/www/html/projects/RISHI/final/rishi-music_server/node_modules/sails-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/bulk/ordered.js:503:10)
    at bulkWrite (/var/www/html/projects/RISHI/final/rishi-music_server/node_modules/sails-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/collection.js:569:8)
    at Collection.insertMany (/var/www/html/projects/RISHI/final/rishi-music_server/node_modules/sails-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/collection.js:471:44)
    at Collection.insert (/var/www/html/projects/RISHI/final/rishi-music_server/node_modules/sails-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/collection.js:722:15)
    at Collection.insert (/var/www/html/projects/RISHI/final/rishi-music_server/node_modules/sails-mongo/lib/collection.js:177:48)
    at Object.module.exports.adapter.create (/var/www/html/projects/RISHI/final/rishi-music_server/node_modules/sails-mongo/lib/adapter.js:282:18)
    at module.exports.create (/var/www/html/projects/RISHI/final/rishi-music_server/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/adapter/dql.js:84:13)
    at bound.createValues (/var/www/html/projects/RISHI/final/rishi-music_server/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/query/dql/create.js:214:16)
    at /var/www/html/projects/RISHI/final/rishi-music_server/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/query/dql/create.js:74:20
    at /var/www/html/projects/RISHI/final/rishi-music_server/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:708:13
    at /var/www/html/projects/RISHI/final/rishi-music_server/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:49:16
    at /var/www/html/projects/RISHI/final/rishi-music_server/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:263:32
    at /var/www/html/projects/RISHI/final/rishi-music_server/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:40:16

Details:  MongoError: topology was destroyed
```

what is the problem. Help me.